# Custom text instead of line numbers in algorithmic

Tags: algorithms

In an algorithm using the `algorithmic` package, I would like to display for some lines a special symbol (e.g. a `+`), instead of their line number. Is this possible?

**Edit:**
Here's a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[tb]
  \caption{My algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \STATE{foo}
  \STATE{bar}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: @MarkHeckmann Unfortunately, I have not.

Comment: @MarkHeckmann I posted an answer yesterday.  Does it work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\plusline}{%
  \let\old@ALC@lno=\ALC@lno%
  \renewcommand{\ALC@lno} {+%
    \global\let\ALC@lno=\old@ALC@lno}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[tb]
  \caption{My algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \STATE{foo}
  \STATE{bar}
  \plusline
  \STATE{foo}
  \STATE{bar}
  \STATE{foo}
  \STATE{bar}
  \STATE{foo}
  \STATE{bar}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

In `algorithmic.sty`, the command `\ALC@lno` is responsible to print the line number.  The above code changes the command temporarily to just output `+` and then to reset itself.

[image: output]