# Custom text instead of line numbers with algpseudocode package

Tags: algorithms, algpseudocode, linenumber

Instead of printing 1:, 2:,.. I want to print Step 1:, Step 2:,.. at the beginning of each line.
Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{My algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State foo
    \State bar
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94721/custom-text-instead-of-line-numbers-in-algorithmic) question, the solution did not work for me, shows

> Command ALC@lno undefined.

I think this is because I am using algpseudocode package, and the solution is using algorithmic package. Moreover, I want the line numbers to be replaced with "Step 1", "Step 2" and so on; but that solution is replacing line numbers with a fixed symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the internal `\ALG@step` macro to add a text before printing the number. The definition below is copied from the `algoritmicx` source (which is used by `algpseudocode`) with the word *Step* added. Because the macro contains the `@` character you need to put `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around the definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\def\ALG@step%
   {%
   \addtocounter{ALG@line}{1}%
   \addtocounter{ALG@rem}{1}%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALG@rem}}{\ALG@numberfreq}}%
      {\setcounter{ALG@rem}{0}\alglinenumber{Step \arabic{ALG@line}}}%
      {}%
   }%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{My algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State foo
    \State bar
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]