How to customize step numbering in the algorithmic package to prefix each line with "Step" in LaTeX?
I am currently working with the algorithmic package and need to modify the output of an algorithm such that each line starts with the word Step followed by the step number. The goal is to have the steps of the algorithm numbered as:
Step 1 Do something
Step 2 Another action
Step 3 Final step
This would replace the default numbering, which only outputs numbers without the "Step" prefix.
Efforts to Achieve the Desired Result Using algorithmic:
I have tried the following approach, but I am unable to achieve the desired output where the line numbers are prefixed with "Step":

Initial Attempt: I tried to use \renewcommand{\ALG@numberline} to add a prefix to the number, but it didn't work as expected since \ALG@numberline is not defined in the algorithmic package.

Example attempt:
\renewcommand{\ALG@numberline}[1]{\textbf{Step~#1}}

However, this method is not working because the algorithmic package doesn't provide a way to access the internal commands like \ALG@numberline.

Using algorithmicx: I also tried switching to the algorithmicx package and managed to achieve the desired result by redefining \alglinenumber:

\renewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{\textbf{Step~#1}}
This worked as expected, but I would like to avoid switching to algorithmicx and prefer to stick to the algorithmic package.
Question:
Is there a way to achieve the same result using the algorithmic package? Specifically, how can I prepend the word "Step" to the line numbers in the algorithm output without switching to the algorithmicx package?
I am looking for a solution that works specifically with the algorithmic package or to improve the available solution. Any help would be appreciated!

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode} % Part of the algorithmicx package
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

% Redefine line numbers to include "Step"
%\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\alglinenumber}[1]{Step~#1.} % Prefix "Step" before the line number
%\makeatother
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{algorithm}[hbt!]
        \caption{Dummy Algorithm}\label{alg:dummy_algorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Require Some requirements 
            \Ensure Ensure all the conditions are met.
            \State $m \gets Z_1$
            \State $\mathrm{sum}_{delta} \gets 1$
            \State $i \gets 1$
            \While{$i \leq m$}
            \State Do something
            \EndWhile
            \State Objectives achieved. 
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
    
\end{document}

Edit 1: The possible answer using the algpseudocode(Part of the algorithmicx package)
Custom text instead of line numbers with algpseudocode package
However, I am curious whether there is any solution using the algorithmic package instead of switching to the algpseudocode package. This is my effort to understand better algorithmic package.
I have used \algsetup{linenosize=\small,linenodelimiter=:}, can this command be customized to fulfill my requirement? Thanks in advance.
Edit 2: The solution provided by Marijn in the comments solves my problems. However, there is a minor issue. My algorithm uses a while loop, and to accommodate the indentation of the while loop, "step 5" (which uses a while loop) onwards gets indented too. How should I rectify that?

Or else maybe a variant of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94721/custom-text-instead-of-line-numbers-in-algorithmic (linked from the other question), i.e., redefine \ALC@lno.

For the pure algorithmic case without algpseudocode you can use the other question that I linked in my comment above. In your case it is even a bit simpler than that answer because you don't want to change the numbering for one line but for all lines. So it would be \makeatletter \newcommand{\stepnumbers}{% \let\old@ALC@lno=\ALC@lno% \renewcommand{\ALC@lno}{Step \old@ALC@lno}% } \makeatother in the preamble and then in the algorithm itself you put \stepnumbers before the first \STATE command.

@Marijn, thanks. It is working. However, there is a minor issue. My algorithm uses a while loop, and to accommodate the indentation of the while loop, "step 5" onwards gets indented too. How should I rectify that?

I'm not sure I understand. When I rewrite your code to use only algorithmic, i.e., use \STATE, \WHILE etc. with upper case, and I apply the solution from the other question as explained in my comment above, I get https://i.sstatic.net/6PkdKHBM.png. Is that not what you want?

As a standalone figure in the \documentclass article in MWE, I got the exact alignment you provided, which solved my problem. However, I suppose that issue may be because of the journal-specific document class. I will dig deeper and get back to this. Anyway, thanks for your help. Anyhow, I suppose it would be fruitful to switch to algpseudocode for future work.

algorithmic defines all the necessary algorithmic commands within the opening definition of the algorithm. This makes adjustments not that straight forward. One way around it is to override the environment through copying it. Then one can insert command updates as needed.
The following code does that, and updates \ALC@it - the "itemized list component of ALgorithmiC" called by \STATE. The original definition of \ALC@it just sets an \item, while the updated one sets \item[Step~<ctr>] (where <ctr> is the appropriate counter representation).

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy\oldalgorithmic\algorithmic
\NewCommandCopy\endoldalgorithmic\endalgorithmic
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{algorithmic}{ O{0} }{%
  \begin{oldalgorithmic}[#1]
    \renewcommand{\ALC@it}{%
      \stepcounter{ALC@rem}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{#1}}{\setcounter{ALC@rem}{0}}{}%
      \stepcounter{ALC@line}%
      \refstepcounter{ALC@unique}%
      \item[\footnotesize Step~\theALC@line:]% Original: \item
      \def\@currentlabel{\theALC@line}%
    }%
}{%
  \end{oldalgorithmic}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Dummy algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \REQUIRE Some requirements 
    \ENSURE Ensure all the conditions are met.
    \STATE $m \gets Z_1$
    \STATE $\mathrm{sum}_{\delta} \gets 1$
    \STATE $i \gets 1$
    \WHILE{$i \leq m$}
      \STATE Do something
    \ENDWHILE
    \STATE Objectives achieved. 
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}

